# is there a way to get the import directly by typing name of module of python in vscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

lets say i have Django in a virtual environment and activated it and now i want to use the built-in user model "User",

so every time i have to look for, then type:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

or CreateView

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
```

etc...

the same thing for every import needed

is there a way to quick-fix that , instead of looking for where this module or this other or ... comes from in the docs every time, is there a way that it suggests or gives the import path??

Comment: You could write a .py file with the imports you like and then you only have to import that one thing. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You're asking that VSCode know the location of every function, class, and variable in every module on the system, whether you have imported it or not.  That's a bit much, don't you think?

Comment: no ,that is not what i meant , i just gave an example of User model ,  let's say i want to use CreateView from the generic views, for example

Comment: @TimRoberts that's actually how it's supposed to work) You have a PYTHONPATH which can be indexed, I would expect VSCode to do this out of the box pretty much like every IDE does. But you have to know the exact name you wanna import. @taha maatof what happens when you just write `CreateView` in the file? For example, In PyCharm if I click alt+enter, it will suggest the import options, maybe you already have this in VSCode as well?

Comment: @Alexandr Tatarinov actually i tried Pycharm and it is working as you described out of the box, but with vscode i got this : "CreateView" is not defined Pylance, even though the correct interpreter is already added

Comment: create snippets with the prefixes `djuser` `djcreateview`